# how are javascript properties added to and looked up on objects?

Tags: javascript, properties, lookup

When adding properties to a JavaScript object are they added in an ordered way (alphabetical etc). And if so does that mean when you lookup a property on a JavaScript object that a quick algorithm is used like a binary tree search? I did a search for this and just found lots of explanations for prototype inheritance which I already understand I'm just interested in how a property is looked up within a single level of the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#prop_access) is a high level description of how v8 does it using hidden classes it then looks up the property value by using the fixed offset provided by the definition of the hidden class. It also confirms that most other implementations use a dictionary type data object.

Comment: You should quote the interesting parts here. Link-only answers are frowned upon here.

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on the implementation. Google's V8 engine probably does it differently than Firefox's JagerMonkey. And they almost certainly does it different than IE6. Looking up a property in an object is just an interface (a fairly common Map interface as programmers would call it). The only thing Javascript guarantees you is the methods of the interface, no details about implementation, and that's a good thing. It could be a hash table (probably) or it could be a linked list (less likely, but possible) or it could even be a binary search tree.

The point is that we don't know how it's implemented, nor should we. And you should make no assumptions about the implementation. As is common with abstraction in programming, just assume it's magic. :)

Comment: I suppose my question is really trying to get at is are properties looked up in a "quick" way? Meaning does the runtime do better than just cycling through an unordered list of properties to eventually find (or find the absence of) the prop you were looking up (so I suppose this slow method would be if it used a linked list). Thanks though.

Comment: That's the problem, we don't know and it doesn't matter. However, you can probably assume that they're looked up as quickly as possible. With the browser wars in full swing, nobody wants to have a slow Javascript engine.

Comment: @0xor1 Calling an object property by name is slower than asking for a variable which was defined in the current scope, but is faster than iterating through, or using a linked-list, by hand. These two are pretty constant, regardless of browser.  What each engine is doing is a mystery.  The order you get items back, from a `for in` might be the same for each loop in the same browser version, but from browser to browser and from version to version, you are not guaranteed to get them alphabetically or in order of insertion, or anything else -- it's an implementation-specific detail.

Comment: @GJK that was the assumption I was making too. I just wondered if anyone knew or there was any documentation to explain what any of the main runtimes do use. Thanks.

Comment: @0xor1, Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table. A similar approach is probably used.

Comment: @0xor1 You can always look at the source code for some browser projects (for instance, the [Chromium source code](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/)) to see how they have implemented it. This is, of course, not indicative of how all browser engines would do it, as indicated by others.